The nodes search doesn't work for me
I've seen in tutorials that they add nodes via search. When searching for nodes by first letters (via search or  Ctrl  +  F ) it shows that there are no results, although I know that these nodes exist.


You search for "Gam" (Gamma?) but there is no such node, at least not visible on the screenshot. If you want to add a new node, it's SHIFT+A, not CTRL+F.

I've seen in tutorials that they add nodes via search.

 Ctrl  +  F  is hotkey for finding existing nodes in your node tree.  Shift  +  A  is for adding nodes. If you start typing after hitting  Shift  +  A , you will enter the search for adding nodes.
